# How to calculate the total amount in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem to calculate the total amount. For example

```
id  name  date  amount
1    A    2017   100
1    A    2018   200
2    B    2017   50
2    B    2016   100
A's total        300
B's total        150
Total            450
```

Select id, name, date, amount form Table1 where date > 2015 order by id, amount;

I want to calculate the total amount for A, B and AB. Also add new column names. Which function should I use? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `grouping sets`:

```
select id, name, date, sum(amount) as amount
from table1
where date > 2015
group by grouping sets ( (id, name, date), (name), () );
```

I'm not sure what new column names you want to add.

EDIT:

Assuming the three key columns are never `NULL`, you can assign names as:

```
select id,
       (case when name is null then 'Total'
             when id is null then 'name' || '''s Total'
             else name
        end) as name
       date, sum(amount) as amount
from table1
where date > 2015
group by grouping sets ( (id, name, date), (name), () );
```

Comment: I want to add column name as A'total, B's total and Total for both A and B. So just put the name in the(name)?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT id , SUM(amount)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```